# Apache2 Fails to start after recent update to 2.4.34, no clue why

Tags: apache-2.4, server-crashes

At 7:57:18PM last night, July 17th Apache2 shut down and quit working.  I didn't notice until earlier today (the 18th.)

**Updates Occurred**: /var/log/apt/history.log shows that there were 3 updates performed:

```
Start-Date: 2018-07-17  19:57:18
Commandline: apt-get -y install apache2 Install: libjansson4:amd64 
(2.7-3, automatic) Upgrade: apache2-data:amd64 (2.4.33- 
3.0+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 2.4.34- 
1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+5), apache2-bin:amd64 (2.4.33- 
3.0+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 2.4.34 
1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+5), apache2:amd64 (2.4.33 
3.0+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org$ End-Date: 2018-07-17  19:57:23

Start-Date: 2018-07-17  19:57:37
Commandline: apt-get -y install apache2-doc
Upgrade: apache2-doc:amd64 (2.4.33-3.0+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 
2.4.34-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+5)
End-Date: 2018-07-17  19:57:39

Start-Date: 2018-07-17  19:57:43
Commandline: apt-get -y install apache2-suexec-custom
Upgrade: apache2-suexec-custom:amd64 (2.4.33- 
3.0+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 2.4.34- 
1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+5)
End-Date: 2018-07-17  19:57:44
```

**Upon Entering**: /etc/init.d/apache2 start

I get:  `Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!`

**systemctl status apache2.service** yields:

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; 
vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-07-18 15:01:46 
MST; 3min 50s ago
  Process: 8835 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, 
status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 21710 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, 
status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 8832 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

**journalctl -xe** gives me this:

```
Jul 18 15:20:04 ns1.[masked].com apachectl[23823]: apache2: Syntax 
error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 
2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/lbmethod_byrequests.load:
```

Line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf reads:

`DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}`

and line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/lbmethod_byrequests.load:

`LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so`

At this point, I'm completely lost.  Line 146 just references the .load file which points to a path to a file that exists...so I don't know what the syntax error is on line 2 of lbmethod_byrequests.load.

Anyone else having trouble with Apache after the update to 2.4.34?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing some of the error. The full error is:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error 
on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/lbmethod_byrequests.load: Cannot load 
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so into server: 
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so: undefined symbol: 
ap_proxy_balancer_get_best_worker
```

It appears to be caused by module load order. *lbmethod_byrequests* depends on *proxy* but *lbmethod_byrequests* is being loaded first, leading to an undefined symbol error that *proxy* would provide if it were loaded.

If you `mv /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/lbmethod_byrequests.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/zzlbmethod_byrequests.load`, Apache starts normally. Unfortunately I can't say why this happens now and didn't before.

Comment: OH MY GOD!  I didn't even see your answer until just now...GARGHLHGLDH!  So much for notifications ;).  So the ZZ just alphabetizes the file so it fires off last...whatever it's doing.  **IT WORKED**  How did you figure that out?  I did see the entire error, eventually.

Comment: All of my certificates for all of my sites seem to be trashed, however.

Comment: Can I buy you lunch or something?  You just saved my butt.

Comment: Simple test environment to reproduce the error and some googling of the missing symbol led to the cause. Happy to have helped. Good luck with the certificate issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the module load order in the proxy.conf in a similar scenario:

I'm running the alpine apache2-proxy package. It fails with:

```
cannot load modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so into server: 
Error relocating /var/www/modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so: 
ap_proxy_balancer_get_best_worker: symbol not found
```

The guys [here](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1084990.html?sid=63bf5483238bc4487fd9dae0b741f85f) were talking about a bug being fixed but the load order still being an issue. I'm not 100% clear on the details but in my instance the proxy config was in a different place:

```
etc/apache2/conf.d/proxy.conf
```

Here I made sure mod_proxy.so was listed before mod_lbmethod_byrequests
Problem solved. Only took me half a day.

Answer (score 1):

The below command worked for me. Earlier I was using php7.4 but after the ubuntu upgrade, the latest version install that is 8.1

```
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo a2enmod php8.1
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

If someone still wants to use PHP 7 or an older version use the below command after the ubuntu upgrade.

```
# PHP version that needs to be disabled
sudo a2dismod php8.1 
# PHP version that needs to be enabled
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Hope it will helpful for someone.